# WPToolkit autocomplete box and searching windows phone maps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I am writing a windows 8 phone app where I have the following use case. My app page has a text box where the user types in three to four letters, immediately I would like to fetch the possible locations from the Maps in the auto complete option. Now 2 questions.

1. Shall I use the WPToolKit AutoCompleteBox for the Text box?
2. What is the API to search the new Maps control in Windows Maps.

Answer (score 1):

I was just doing this myself and I have alas but one option : do it yourself.

In order to do this you are going to need to use the geocoding api in order to search for coordinates and address from say a  single, or a few letters. The link where this is located is at

http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/maps-and-navigation/guide-to-the-wp8-maps-api.html#toc_Searchingforanaddress

Once your async query returns you can put the array into list items in a ListPicker (since I assume that's how you want to do it). If not then of course you can just use the addresses and place them anywhere.

What you need is the following - I'm updating a List bound to a LongListSelector.

```
  this.DestinationsList.Clear();
       // Add all results to MyCoordinates for drawing the map markers
       for (int i = 0; i < e.Result.Count; i++)
       {
            MyCoordinates.Add(e.Result[i].GeoCoordinate);
            MapAddress address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
            String stringAddress = address.City;
            if (i < 6) {
                this.DestinationsList.Add(stringAddress);
            }

       }
```

Hope this helps to get your own search box up and running. After this you can also filter by locations close to you etc. but you'll need to write your own code for that also.

Comment: Oh I forgot to say - no don't use the autocomplete box - I doubt it goes well for many place names.